# How Do I Check If A Field Has Content/Value in NetSuite SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I tried to check if a custom field has content in NetSuite SuiteScript. However, my ways do not work.

I have tried the following methods:
1) !isEmptyVariantVar(nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_attachment'))
2) nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_attachment') != null

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking into SuiteScript 2.0? I believe SuiteScript 1.0 will continue working, but no more support will be available from NetSuite. Once you get used to SutieScript 2.0, it is easier and a lot more functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if(fldVal != '')
{ //TO DO}
```

I believe "!fldVal" will just check for a boolean value of "false".

Comment: "!fldVal" is a "falsy" See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 1):

```
var fldVal = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_myfield');
if(!fldVal){
   // my field had no value
}
```

Your variable will be NULL.

Comment: var fldVal = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_attachment');
      if(stTransRecordType == "VENDORBILL" && !fldVal){
            //TO DO}

Hi dcrs, I tried your method, but the TO DO part was still not executed for some reasons.

Comment: Please note that this field is a Document type field.

Comment: @RhysJ try using lowercase for your record type "vendorbill". I think it's failing on that.